# Codeigniter URL routing - SEO concerns

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, routes, seo

We have a good old website where all the pages are static and we are updating them by editing the HTML files. Every redesign is a lot of work for us since we copy and paste all the texts from old to new design. If we need to change any single thing about design, we need to change it in all other pages one by one.

Now we have developed a site by using Codeigniter and want to replace that static pages with database-driven pages. We will put all the content to the database so we will have just one product page and retrieve any product info according to the query string.

The problem is we don't want to change the old urls with the new Codeigniter urls because of search engine ranking concerns.

URLs in the old website are like these:

```
example.com/code1001.php
example.com/code1002.php
example.com/very-good-product-1003.php
example.com/brand-new-product.php
example.com/product-listing.php
```

The Codeigniter URLS in the new website are like these:

```
example.com/products/details/code1001
example.com/products/details/code1002
example.com/products/details/code1003
example.com/products/listing
```

After a quick research, I thought that I can use CI's routes.php to display database-driven pages when user/google hit to the old URL.
I can use the below code to do that.

```
$route['code1001.php'] = "products/details/code1001";
$route['example.com/very-good-product-1003.php'] = "products/details/code1003";
$route['brand-new-product.php'] = "products/details/1004";
$route['product-listing.php'] = "products/listing";
```

I don't want this to be a 301 or 302 redirect, I just want to replace the static pages with the database driven pages and leave the urls same.

**Do you think that this will have a negative effect on SEO? Is Google able to notice this routing?**

Comment: you can do google indexing by your URL

Answer (score 1):

Best Way For dynamic routing is

```
$route['confirm_registration/(:any)']=  "login/confirm_registration/$1";
```

For redirect you can use .htaccess